# Laravel Validation: Validating OR instead of AND

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I am trying to validation a field to see if the value is an integer OR an array. The rule below check if the value is an integer AND array.

```
'field' => "integer|array",
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use `OR` you will need to create a [custom validation rule](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules).

`'field' => 'integer_or_array'`

```
Validator::extend('integer_or_array', function($attribute, $value){
    return is_int($value) || is_array($value);
});
```

---

```
Validator::extend('integer_or_array', function($attribute, $value){
    return is_int($value) || is_array($value);
});
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), ['field' => 'integer_or_array']);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a treat